# Figuring out functions that aren't being called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to iterate through directories to retrieve files using Google Chrome's Filesystem API.

On line 25 `files.push(file);`, trying to populate the `files` array doesn't seem to get called. However if I replace this with `console.log(file);` it works all of the sudden but only with that function.

Can anyone explain what's going on and what I'm doing wrong? Drop any dir into the following JSFiddle box to see:

http://jsfiddle.net/tekky/ZXU8v/8/

Code:

```
var dndbox = $(".dndbox")[0];

dndbox.addEventListener("dragenter", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
},false);

dndbox.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
},false);

dndbox.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var itemList = e.dataTransfer.items;

    var files = [];

    var traverse = function(entry)
        {
            if (entry.isFile) {
                entry.file(function(file){
                    files.push(file);
                });
            } else if (entry.isDirectory){
                var dR = entry.createReader();
                dR.readEntries(function(entries) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++)
                    {
                        traverse(entries[i]);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
            var e = itemList[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
            traverse(e);
        }

    console.log(files); //Empty?

},false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback you provide to `entry.file()` is asynchronous, so it returns for each file *after* the `console.log(file)`.

If you drop in a `console.log(files)` on line 25, you can see it getting updated as each callback is fired.  So if you want to do something with all the files, you'll need to wait for every callback to execute.

Here's a simple example of waiting until all the files have returned: http://jsfiddle.net/6Tn8W/.

I would also recommend checking out [promises](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/11/asynchronous-programming-in-javascript-with-promises.aspx?Redirected=true).

EDIT: Here's an example using promises and the [when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) function. This is the first time I've used jQuery's implementation of promises, so there might be a better way to do this :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Lsuz2/

Comment: Promises looks... promising hehe. However you can only call resolve once, how can I get around this since the function is recursive? Care to provide an example along with your answer?

Comment: Updated my answer for you, also learned a few things myself! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Too bad standard JS doesn't have `.when()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

I wanted to implement it using this but it doesn't seem possible?

Comment: Wow never knew about that, what about `Promise.all()`?

Comment: I don't know since I don't even know where to start. I'm having a hard time grasping the concept of a `Promise`. I get the gist of it, but I think it'll take me a while to understand the flow. Plus the different syntax isn't helping either. :(

Comment: Don't worry, it takes a bit to get used to.  Try taking a look at https://github.com/kriskowal/q, it has pretty good explanations and examples.  It's also what a lot of JS libraries/frameworks use for promises.

Comment: So it turns out I didn't need promises at all. Instead of collecting the files I used a callback to pass the file instead on line 25. Before it didn't work for what I needed it for because I was using the same XHR object instead of the new one each time. This coincidentally had similar behavior of the function not being called more than once since it's one XHR object per request. :)

Comment: Ah, so it was a completely different problem! Glad you figured it out though.

Comment: Turns out I'm gonna have to collect the files after all for something else now though. LOL Back to messing with promises!

Comment: Here's another good link explaining them: http://sebastianfastner.de/javascript-promises-explained.html